# Regular expression to use which matches text before .html and after /

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url

With this string

`http://sfsdf.com/sdfsdf-sdfsdf/sdf-as.html`

I need to get `sdf-as`

with this

`hellow-1/yo-sdf.html`

I need `yo-sdf`

Comment: `/^.*\/([a-z\-]+)\.html$/` I'll leave the C#-specifics to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you want you need:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"/([^/]*)\.html$");
Match match = re.Match("http://sfsdf.com/sdfsdf-sdfsdf/sdf-as.html");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); //Or do whatever you want with the value
```

This needs `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of the file to work.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this. The following uses lookarounds to match only the filename portion. It actually allows no `/` if such is the case:

```
string[] urls = {
   @"http://sfsdf.com/sdfsdf-sdfsdf/sdf-as.html",
   @"hellow-1/yo-sdf.html",
   @"noslash.html",
   @"what-is/this.lol",
};

foreach (string url in urls) {
   Console.WriteLine("[" + Regex.Match(url, @"(?<=/|^)[^/]*(?=\.html$)") + "]");
}
```

This prints:

```
[sdf-as]
[yo-sdf]
[noslash]
[]
```

#### How the pattern works

There are 3 parts:

- `(?<=/|^)` : a positive lookbehind to assert that we're preceded by a slash `/`, or we're at the beginning of the string
- `[^/]*` : match anything but slashes
- `(?=\.html$)`: a positive lookahead to assert that we're followed by `".html"` (literally on the dot)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

---

#### A non-regex alternative

Knowing regex is good, and it can do wonderful things, but you should always know how to do basic string manipulations without it. Here's a non-regex solution:

```
static String getFilename(String url, String ext) {
   if (url.EndsWith(ext)) {
     int k = url.LastIndexOf("/");
     return url.Substring(k + 1, url.Length - ext.Length - k - 1);
   } else {
     return "";
   }
}
```

Then you'd call it as:

```
getFilename(url, ".html")
```

#### API links

- [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), [`EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), and [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

---

#### Attachments

- [Source code and output on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/UFzE2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string url = "http://sfsdf.com/sdfsdf-sdfsdf/sdf-as.html";
Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"/([^/]+)\.html$");
if (match.Success)
{
    string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Result:

```
sdf-as
```

However it would be a better idea to use the [**`System.URI`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28VS.71%29.aspx) class to parse the string so that you correctly handle things like `http://example.com/foo.html?redirect=bar.html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex pattern = new Regex(".*\/([a-z\-]+)\.html");
Match match = pattern.Match("http://sfsdf.com/sdfsdf-sdfsdf/sdf-as.html");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found :(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one makes the slash and dot parts optional, and allows the file to have any extension:

`new Regex(@"^(.*/)?(?<fileName>[^/]*?)(\.[^/.]*)?$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);`

But I still prefer Substring(LastIndexOf(...)) because it is far more readable.